# Python-Pyo None-Type error

Tags: python, pyo

I'm trying to run the following **code**,

but I'm getting a `None-Type error`:

```
from pyo import *
import random

s = Server().boot()
s.start()


fr = SigTo(value=200, time=0.5, init=200)
a = SineLoop(freq=fr, feedback=0.08, mul=.3).out()

def new_freq():
    fr.value = random.randrange(100, 600, 10)

pat = Pattern(function=new_freq, time=1).play()
```

And the **error**:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'randrange'

If I am using the `python interpreter` and type in the commands one after another, it works.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You didn't show whole code. You have `random = {something}` somewhere (possibly with `global random` statement which leaks this assignment to global scope). Keep in mind that `for random in ...` or `with ... as random` will still be an assignment,  although slightly more "convoluted".

Answer (score 1):

you might have created a `random.py` file, rename it and delete the `random.pyc`.

to verify check `random.__file__`, it will show you the source path of the module from where it is imported.